# How to prepare a CSV file with 2 DateTime Columns for Process Mining

Tags: python, data-processing

I am using **pm4py** library of python for Process Mining. I have a CSV file with `ID`, `Activity_name`, `Activity_start_date` and `Activity_end_Date`. I need to take into account both the start date and end date. I need to use both start and end date for visualising the process and identifying bottlenecks.

In this library I can only name the timestamp to `time:timestamp` to be able to use it.

Is there a way to use both the `start_time` and `end_time columns`?

Comment: Could you add what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have started learning Process Mining a few days back only.
I know that we have to set the name if column as 'time:timestamp'. So I set the start time as this column, but I am unable to understand how I can use the end_time column